# How do I hide the left thumbnail panel?

Tags: google-slides

In Google Slides, I want to **hide or remove the left thumbnail panel**, as shown below.

In Microsoft Powerpoint, you can drag the left panel to be closed, but I can't figure out how to do this in Google Slides. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Has anybody figured out a way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same question and it seems like Google still doesn't provide the option. If you really need to get rid of it though, you can use this hack as a solution as of May 5, 2020.

Open inspect element from menu bar -> Go to div id = "docs-editor-container" -> div id = "docs-editor" -> table class = "two-panel-layout" -> tbody -> tr -> Delete td class = "filmstrip".

[image: Result]

This is the result. Now you can have a much wider view of your slide.

Comment: You can set `display: none` as well.

Answer (score 3):

## Toggle with a Bookmark

I tweaked the bookmarklet code from [this blog](http://jgmalcolm.com/hide-side-panel) (I target the `<td>` by class instead of its content by ID). Normally I would give you a JavaScript link to drag to your bookmark bar; but I can't work out how to share such a link in a StackExchange solution.

You can edit an existing bookmark & paste this as the URL:

```
javascript:(function() {var e=document.getElementsByClassName('filmstrip')[0];e.style.display=(e.style.display!='none')?'none':'table-cell';})();
```

Chrome wanted it to be URL-encoded:

```
javascript:(function() %7Bvar e%3Ddocument.getElementsByClassName(%27filmstrip%27)%5B0%5D%3Be.style.display%3D(e.style.display!%3D%27none%27)%3F%27none%27:%27table-cell%27%3B%7D)()%3B
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there isn't a built-in feature to hide the thumbnail panel as you can see in the View menu:

[image]

- **Show ruler** Shows/hides the ruler
- **Show speaker notes** Shows/hides the speaker notes
- **Full screen** Shows/hides the Google Slides menu bar, toolbar and side panel